# Find square with latitude and longitude for given lat and lng and distance

Tags: distance, spherical-geometry, latitude-longitude, mathematics

I have the coordinates of some point, lets say `lat` and `lng`,  I want to find the latitude and longitude of top left and bottom right corners of the square, whose sides are located `k` kilometers from the initial point.

[image]

Comment: My guess with no real knowledge on geodesy is that you need to find a function for calculating geodesic distances and then find points which are (square root(2*k) apart from the centre point and to azimuths of 45, 135, 225, and 315 degrees. Program FORWARD could be worth trying http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/Inv_Fwd/Inv_Fwd.html

Comment: @user30184, Thanks for the link will take a look